# Best, average, and worst case time complexities of insert() in std::set and std::map

Tags: c++, time-complexity, std

I just wanted to double-check, but I believe that the best, average, and worst-case time complexities should all be O(log(size of the set)) because of the red-black tree implementation of std::map and std::set?

Comment: Yes, approximately they are. Exact complexities [are here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8D63v.png) at page [https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/insert](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/insert).

Comment: See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/insert#Complexity

Comment: Thanks but doesn't the cpp reference page only show the average case -- I don't see the best and worst case time complexities anywhere

Comment: `std::unordered_map` is typically a hash table and has O(1) insert.  `std::map` is typically a tree and has O(lg N) insert.

Comment: @selbie O(lg N) for the best case as well?

Comment: If your `std::set` is implemented as an RBTree, which I believe they all main implementations are, then all are `O(logN)`.  If you have a hint you can get `O(1)`

Comment: As you can also see, when giving the right position to insert; it becomes amortized `O(1)`, so best case might be `O(1)`.

Comment: I don't see how cppreference is showing 'average' time. Big-O is, by definition, the worst-case.

Comment: @sweenish except for things like "amortized constant time," very common in hash tables.

Comment: The Standard says `insert` has the same behavior (including complexity) as `emplace`, and also that `emplace` has logarithmic complexity.   https://eel.is/c++draft/associative.reqmts#general-51  and  https://eel.is/c++draft/map.modifiers#2

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are correct, they are truly O(log N) in the worst case.  Unlike typical hash tables where occasional rehashing may make one operation much worse than typical.